# Unable upload image file in ASP.NET Core Web API - POST method

Tags: asp.net-core, file-upload, webapi, boundary, iformfile

I was trying to upload a single image file. Sample code is as follows:

```cs
        /// <summary>
        /// Uploads a single image document 
        /// </summary>
        /// <returns></returns>
        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{id}/scan-doc-image")]
        //[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadImage(int id, IFormFile file)
        {
            // more validation goes here.
            if (file == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // save image if any
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                var uploads = Path.Combine(_envirnment.WebRootPath, "uploads");

                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
```

Here is what I noticed:

1. Making a call to this API automatically STOPS the service. I tried many many times and it always shuts it down. It didn't stop the service when I make other API calls. Just FYI
2. I tried making a call from POSTMAN as well. This time, it didn't close the service but I keep getting errors: `Failed to read the request form. Missing content-type boundary.`
   Note that, I am specifing Content-Type as `multipart/form-data`. And when I specify the boundary a number less than max, it still errors. Even when I uncomment the `RequestFormLimit` attribute you see above, it didn't help either.

So what I am missing here? All I need it to upload a single image file.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried making a call from POSTMAN as well. This time, it didn't close
> the service but I keep getting errors: Failed to read the request
> form. Missing content-type boundary. Note that, I am specifing
> Content-Type as multipart/form-data. And when I specify the boundary a
> number less than max, it still errors. Even when I uncomment the
> RequestFormLimit attribute you see above, it didn't help either.

[image]
There is no need to add a `Content-Type` header manually. You are overriding the value set by **Postman**. Just select `form-data` in POST request and send your request to see if it works. No need to set `header` when `form-data` is posted. Just **remove** the `Content-Type` and **upload** as below.

[image]

### Note for the path which may causes error

If you are using Web API project, you will get null in `_envirnment.WebRootPath`. There is no `wwww` directory in Web API project.

[image]

### Solution

Change `WebRootPath`

```
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_envirnment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
```

to `ContentRootPath`

```
        var uploads = Path.Combine(_envirnment.ContentRootPath, "uploads");
```

### Test

[image]

### Codes of controller

If the specified folder "uploads" does not exist, create it firstly , and then save file to this folder. If the folder already exists, just save the file in it.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace WebAPIDemos.Controllers
{

    [ApiController]
    [Route("[controller]")]
    public class FileController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly IWebHostEnvironment _envirnment;

        public FileController(IWebHostEnvironment appEnvironment)
        {
            _envirnment = appEnvironment;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("{id}/scan-doc-image")]
        //[RequestFormLimits(ValueLengthLimit = int.MaxValue, MultipartBodyLengthLimit = int.MaxValue)]
        public async Task<ActionResult> UploadImage(int id, IFormFile file)
        {
            // more validation goes here.
            if (file == null)
            {
                return BadRequest();
            }

            // save image if any
            if (file.Length > 0)
            {
                //var uploads = Path.Combine(_envirnment.WebRootPath, "uploads");
                var uploads = Path.Combine(_envirnment.ContentRootPath, "uploads");

                var destinationDirectory = new DirectoryInfo(uploads);

                if (!destinationDirectory.Exists)
                    destinationDirectory.Create();


                using (var fileStream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(uploads, file.FileName), FileMode.Create))
                {
                    await file.CopyToAsync(fileStream);
                }
            }

            return Ok();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks @Lightman, not specifying content-type helps. Debugging however shows still, `Content-Type: multipart/form-data` `with some large boundary number` is sent by postman still. So its really not that the content type was wrong but **somehow, even when I used just what postman is sending and specifying it, it didn't work**. Swagger still close the app when trying to upload an image. and root folder exists for other reason and works well.

Comment: *Uploads where the payload is just the raw file contents are not supported in Swagger 2.0, because they are not multipart/form-data.* Hi, @Koref ,I found  [Can I upload files via PUT?](https://swagger.io/docs/specification/2-0/file-upload/)
 from `swagger.io`. Hope it helps.